# Cannot get data from mysql query to controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello I am using codeigniter framework for a project, I have a controller which is calling the data from a model function. Here is the controller.

```
  public function getThirdPartyRR($token){
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        // $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        // Following is loaded automatically in the constructor.
        //$this->load->model('user_profile');
        $userid = $this->myajax->getUserByAuth($token);
        if ($userid){
            $this->load->model("riskrating_page");
            /* If we have an impersonated user in the session, let's use him/her. */
            if (isset($_SESSION['userImpersonated'])) {
                if ($_SESSION['userImpersonated'] > 0) {
                    $userid = $_SESSION['userImpersonated'];
                }
            }
            // $resultList value could be null also.
            $result = $this->riskrating_page->getThirdPartydata($userid);             
            /* Little bit of magic :). */
            $thirdpartylist = json_decode(json_encode($result), true); 
            $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode($thirdpartylist));
        } else {
            return $this->output->set_status_header('401', 'Could not identify the user!');
        }
    } else {
        return $this->output->set_status_header('400', 'Request not understood as an Ajax request!');
    }   
}
```

And here is the query function in the model where I get the data from.

```
function getThirdPartydata($id){

      $query = 'SELECT b.text_value as Company, a.third_party_rr_value
                FROM user_thirdparty_rr a 
                inner join text_param_values b
                    on a.third_party_rr_type = b.text_code and
                    b.for_object = \'user_thirdparty_rr\'
                WHERE a.Owner = '.$id. ' and 
                    a.UPDATE_DT is null;';

    }
```

But when I debug it using netbeans, its shows that in my controller in the **$result** function I get null meaning I couldnt grab any data from mysql.

Here is the search result from mysql. [image: result]

Comment: what is the name of controller is it myajax

Comment: @saurabhkamble hey I already got it working, but thanks for asking !! :D

Comment: update your question with name as it will be helpful for others

Comment: @saurabhkamble I will from next time, Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only write your query not fetch any data from your query result

```
function getThirdPartydata($id){

      $query = "SELECT b.text_value as Company, a.third_party_rr_value
            FROM user_thirdparty_rr a 
            inner join text_param_values b
                on a.third_party_rr_type = b.text_code and
                b.for_object = 'user_thirdparty_rr'
            WHERE a.Owner = '$id' and 
                a.UPDATE_DT is null";
             $this->db->query($query);// execute your query
             return $query->result_array();// fetch data

    }
```

Comment: Thanks!! I totally forgot to add that function, too much coding broke my head XD .

Comment: It's happens sometime !! enjoy!!